# How can I use Pigeonhole here or is there any other way?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let m be a positive integer and let S denote the set of positive integers less than equal to
m that are relatively prime to m. Then Prove that for each x belongs to S, there is a
unique y belongs to S such that xy =1 (mod m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, pigeonhole is fine here. Suppose there are no such $y\in S$ that $xy\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ for some $x$, then $|\{xy|y\in S\}|<|S|$ but this implies that there are some $y_1,\,y_2$ ($y_1\not\equiv y_2\pmod{m}$) that $xy_1\equiv xy_2\pmod{m}$ but $m|x(y_1-y_2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $m|(y_1-y_2)$ (because $(x,m)=1$), a contradiction, QED.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that multiplication by $x$ is injective as a map $S\to S$ (equivalently $m|xy\implies m|y$) then you can use the pigeonhole principle to conclude that multiplication by $x$ is surjective as a map $S \to S$.

In particular there must be some $y\in S$ such that $xy=1$.